# Google Chrome Extension Popup not loading when using jquery

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**Problem:**
I'm trying to use jquery in my Google Chrome extension. It doesn't seem to be working. I've tried adding it to my manifest referencing local copies of the jquery file and I've also tried adding different directives to allow remote access to a CDN hosting it, both solutions I found from StackOverflow.

**Symptom:**
When I click on the top right action button which is suppose to launch popup.html it does nothing but if I right click and select "Inspect Popup" the popup loads with all the functionality from the jquery includes. Any Ideas? I've included my manifest below.

**Possible Clue:** Adding timing delays actually make the popup render and the jquery code execute then shortly after the popup exits prematurely on its own, essentially crashing silently.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "My extension",
  "description": "A test extension.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons":{"128": "icon_512.png"},
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-3.1.1.min.js","events.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
      "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Click here!"
  }
}
```

**Jquery**

Inside popup.js I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Random output!");
});
```

But if I do this it works momentarily:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    // Code here
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Jquery works for a little bit!!!");
});

},1000);
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #content {
            background-color: yellow;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <button id="checkPage">Start</button>
    </div>

     <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Popup and background page are different documents. Do you load jQuery in popup.html? If yes, show it.

Comment: @wOxxOm That should be implied by my manifest file and my description. The jquery you see is for popup.js. I will add the popup.html file as well.

Comment: I tried your code here, it works properly on Version 54.0.2840.50 beta-m (64-bit)

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll try that over the weekend and let you know the results.

Comment: Looks like you were right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Granga pointed out above, this issue was caused by a version compatibility issue. So far, it seems the latest version of jQuery with the latest version of Google Chrome works fine. If anyone experiences an issue like this in the future try upgrading jQuery and/or Chrome.